# How to mavenize eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, buckminster

Current state:
Multi-module Java 6 project using Eclipse plugins, application is distributed for Windows platform only as an exe file with directories with many jars and some init and configuration files. These client distribution is build via Jenkins using Eclipse Buckminster plugin. These project was written around years 2010-2012 and desperately needs refresh.

I mavenized project, which means that each module has now its own pom.xml with dependecies. All modules were successfully built using `mvn install` command.

Question is how to build and distribute complete application with maven and say goodbye to jenkins & buckminster.

Where I see problem(s):

- I don't fully understand what Buckminster actually do and how to set up properly OSGi/Eclipse Equinox launcher. There are few files like .cspex, .cquery, .rmap and even some Ant xml files where some magic happened, but it's not clear for me.
- Is it even possible to use Maven (maven shade plugin) to build such app? Has somebody experience with it?

Comment: Are you saying this is an Eclipse RCP? You can build RCPs using maven with Eclipse Tycho - so for example [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that this is something what I've been looking for.